# CSV with javascript is deleting spaces when download

Tags: javascript, csv

I am using this code to create and download a CSV file with javascrip using an array of JSON as source data

```
var csvRows = [];
//Title for csv columns
csvRows.push('ID,Date,Name');

//cicle for array of JSON
for(i=0;i<this.leads.length;i++;{
    //leads is the name of the array
    csvRows.push(leads[i].ID+','+leads[i].Date+','+leads[i].Name); 
}
var csvString = csvRows.join("%0A");
var a         = document.createElement('a');
a.href        = 'data:attachment/csv,' + csvString;
a.target      = '_blank';
a.download    = 'ReporteLeads.csv';
a.click();
```

The problem is that when the file is dowloaded all space characters are removed and the ones like `á,é,í,ó,ú` or `ñ` are changed to something like this `Ã©`. If I make a `console.log()` of the `csvString` variable I can see the string perfectly without this problems but in the actual file all is messed up.

Can someone help me with this issue? I don't know why it is happening or how to solve it

Comment: Use `data:text/csv;charset=UTF-8` as the mime.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helps with spaces, but i get the same with accents and `ñ` characters. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: You should checkout `blobs` for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `attachment/csv` as MIME type and `utf-8` as your charset.

```
var href = 'data:attachment/csv;charset=utf-8,' + csvString;
```